# How to check if filters work? - Testing filters

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I've got a filter:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/Mvc02")
public class Filter02 implements Filter {
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        some code...
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

And servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Mvc02", urlPatterns = "/Mvc02")
public class Mvc02 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        some code...
    }
}
```

When I go to my browser and type http://localhost:8080/servletjee_war_exploded/Mvc02 it gives me the servlet. Shouldn't it give me the filter first? How to run the filter?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a filter to only apply to certain URL patterns (and if you are using spring), then you would have to register the filter using a FilterRegistrationBean

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter02> loggingFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<Filter02> registrationBean 
      = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        
    registrationBean.setFilter(new Filter02());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/Mvc02");
        
    return registrationBean;    
}
```